# Connecting bak database file to asp.net website using Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, database

Sorry for the noob question. Someone has insisted me that it is possible to connect the `.bak` file to the asp.net website by just using connection string in the `web.config` only. However, I am in the midst of confusion because it doesn't make any sense to me because the `.bak` file is the backup file for the SQL Server.

My real question is, is it possible to connect it without dealing with SQL Server? What are the alternatives and suggestion you have?

Here's the example of `web.config` file he shown to me.....

```
<add name="accountConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=\data\websiteXl.bak; Initial Catalog=websiteXl;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I have tried alternatives like using `.mdf` too....

```
<add name="accountConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=\data\websiteXl.mdf; Initial Catalog=websiteXl;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to connect SQL Server database which is in .bak format to the ASP.net web application that I have created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932743/i-want-to-connect-sql-server-database-which-is-in-bak-format-to-the-asp-net-web)

Comment: This is utter crap - you cannot just connect to a `.bak` file, you're right (and that *"someone"* is plain wrong). You will need to **restore** that `.bak` file onto a SQL Server instance, and after that's done, **THEN** you can use that database

Answer (score 0):

This is utter crap - you cannot just connect to a `.bak` file, you're right (and that *"someone"* is plain wrong).

You will need to **restore** that `.bak` file onto a SQL Server instance, and after that's done, **THEN** you can use that database

Comment: How about if I use mdf file.... It is not possible right unless you attach the database to the SQL server using the "AttachDbFileName" code inside the webconfig provided that you have an admin access to access the sqlserver?

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't possible. The backup file generated by SQL Server (usually with a `.BAK` file extension) is a compressed backup file that's not directly usable, generally.

The only thing you can really do with it is to restore the database, or make a copy of that "snapshot" of the database on another server, or the like.

There are some tools (like Red-Gate's SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare) which can show you the differences between a backup file and a live database, or between two backup files.  But, that wouldn't help you connect to it through an ASP.NET page.